# NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/search/ui/text/TextSearchQueryProvider

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a plugin for eclipse. When calling `TextSearchQueryProvider sqProvider = TextSearchQueryProvider.getPreferred();`, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

The funny thing is, I only get this on the exported jar-plugin, not while debugging the plugin. I figured, it might be related to exporting the `org.eclipse.search`-plugin, but that plugin is so basic, that eclipse doesn't run without it anyway. So I guess the plugin should be there.

I am running eclipse photon (4.8.0).

Some more clarifications:
I have specified `org.eclipse.search` as dependency in `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Require-Bundle: javax.inject,
 org.eclipse.search;bundle-version="3.0.0";visibility:=reexport,
 ....
```

I have imported `org.eclipse.search.ui.text.TextSearchQueryProvider`

Do I need to do anything else, that I am not aware of?

Addition:
The plug-in related views did not show any obvious problems.
Specifically, the 'org.eclipse.search'-dependency is being satisfied by the version '3.11.200.v20180503-1856', which to me implies, that the plugin has been successfully linked?

Comment: Do you really have `Required-Bundle` in the MANIFEST.MF - it should be `Require-Bundle` (and there should be a blank at the start of the second line).

Comment: You are very much correct. I didn't copy the string, I just retyped it (badly). The String is as you describe. I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Is there any error output in the console?

Comment: Sadly, the log does not shot any problems, other than a subversion problem, which seems unrelated. I am trying to debug with the plugin-related views now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem vanished, after I exported the plug-in with another version postfix.
I had originally called the postfix "beta". After giving it a new postfix with date,
the dependency tree seems to work correctly. It might be that the original package was bad and misconfigured in the MANIFEST, and only after reexporting with a different name, the pacakge dependencies were reevaluated corrrectly.